# Grails how to log security plugin activity

Tags: security, grails, logging, plugins

We have Spring Security configured in our Grails application, but it looks like we haven't configured completely correctly. It is intercepting every single piece loading, and each page loading is taking a very long time.

How do I log all the security plugin activity?

Comment: You can implement ApplicationListeners that listen for authentication and authorization events and log those. see http://www.redtoad.ca/ataylor/2011/05/logging-spring-security-events-in-grails/

Comment: This doesn't answer your question about logging spring security activity, but it sounds like you need to add URL mappings to allow all access to your resources (things like CSS, images, js, etc.) Also, note that there is a difference between the _rendered_ resource URLs than what you might expect.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe using `log4j`:

```
info 'org.springframework.security'
```

or this new plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-eventlog